# Encode - String bytes length

Tags: perl, svn, character-encoding, perl5.10

I've file `file1.pl`:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

my @flist = `svn diff --summarize ...`;

foreach my $file (@flist) {
  my $foo = "$one/$file";
  use bytes;
  print(bytes::length($one)."\n");
  print(bytes::length($file)."\n");
  print(bytes::length($foo)."\n");
}
# 76
# 31
# 108
```

and `file2.pl` with the same main logic. But in `file2.pl` the output is:

```perl
# 76
# 31
# 110 <-- ?
```

Both files have the same encoding (ISO-8859-1). For the same result as in `file1.pl` I've to use

```perl
my $foo = "$one/".decode('UTF-8', $file);
```

in `file2.pl`. What could be the reason for that difference or the requirement of `decode('UTF-8', $file)` in `file2.pl`? Seems to be related to [What if I don't decode?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq#What-if-I-don%27t-decode?) but in which manner and only in `file2.pl`? Thx.

Perl v5.10.1

Comment: You don't appear to have told us in what way file2.pl differs from file1.pl? Or are you saying that they're the same apart from the "my $foo = ..."  line?

Comment: Sorry, very difficult zu explain. `file2.pl` is a large file of about 1700 lines of code. `file1.pl` is the extraction of the relevant logic of `file2.pl` for debugging purposes. But I cannot find the reason why the encoding in `file1.pl` works in other way than in `file2.pl`. The concatenation of `$one/$file` works obviously different in `file1.pl` and `file2.pl` regarding to internal encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use bytes.

> **Use of this module for anything other than debugging purposes is strongly discouraged.**

`bytes::length` gets the length of the internal storage of a string. It's useless.

---

> *What could be the reason for that difference*

`$one` and `$file` contained strings stored using different internal storage formats. One needed to be converted for a concatenation to occur.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use bytes qw( );
use Encode qw( encode );

sub dump_lengths {
   my $s = shift;
   say
      join " ",
         length( $s ),
         length( encode( "UTF-8", $s ) ),
         bytes::length( $s );
}
                         # +------ Length of string
my $x = chr( 0xE9 );     # | +---- Length of its UTF-8 encoding
my $y = chr( 0x2660 );   # | | +-- Length of internal storage
                         # | | |
dump_lengths( $x );      # 1 2 1
dump_lengths( $y );      # 1 3 3

my $z = $x . $y;

dump_lengths( $z );      # 2 5 5
```